# VS2015 Internal Compiler Error when using inheriting constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, internal-compiler-error

Here's a 10-line C++11 program, vastly simplified from a program I'm working on:

```
template <typename T> class Base { public:
    template <typename S> Base(S x) {}
};
template <typename T> class Child : public Base<T> { public:
    using Base<T>::Base;
};
template <> class Child<int> : public Base<int> { public:
    using Base<int>::Base;
};

int main()
{
    Child<int> child(8.0f);
}
```

MSVC 2015 outputs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  filename.cpp
1>path\to\filename(10): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1393)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

N.B. MSVC 2015 support for inheriting constructors [is new with that version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

I've already submitted a bug report on this, since at the very least the compiler should not crash.  However, can I have confirmation that this is correct C++ usage/a workaround?

Bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1590961)

Comment: 0_0 what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @DavidHaim: It's an inheriting constructor declaration.

Comment: What else do you expect from MSCV? Workaround: use a decent compiler, such as clang, instead.

Comment: What is "MSCV", @Walter?

Comment: This is not a program, and you can improve the code's readability by eliding the unnecessary `public`s: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/164072087e303251 Going further, I would actually advise making it slightly longer but with better spacing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b1fe7c6d2509a97 Just a thought.

Comment: Please link to your bug report, for reference.

Comment: @imallett: Probably worth raising an issue on Connect, too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I sent it via the built-in reporter in the IDE. I have had [problems](http://superuser.com/questions/942441/i-cant-submit-a-bug-report-because-the-bug-reporter-has-a-bug) submitting it through connect. If someone here could submit it, that would be great.¶ If you just want a shorter bug, here's a tweetable version: `#define t template<typename T=int>//cause ICE\nt class B{t B(T){}};t class C:B<>{using B::B;};template<>class C<>:B<>{using B::B;};C<int>c(1)`.

Comment: I don't see the value in making it unreadable, personally.

Comment: The page works fine. Choose your compiler from the dropdown list and the form will load.

Comment: "To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above" – o.O Sure, instead of MS fixing their buggy compiler, you should carefully craft your code so that it doesn't accidentally trigger their bug. Well done!

Comment: @imallett I think your connect bug report needs more detail. You should at least provide the error message (like you have here) rather than just the smartass comments.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I can't edit any of the fields; only upload new documents. In any case, I don't especially regret going for simplicity. Simply-expressed problems are cluttered by extraneous detail. I only added the output here because it's SO. MS should be able to figure out what their own compiler prints.

Comment: @imallett You don't consider sticking the _in 10 lines_ phrase at the end to be extraneous detail?

Comment: @BetaCarotin touché. Note though, that it helps clarify that the problem can be reproduced in a simple example, not in some huge codebase. When people report bugs this way to me, I appreciate it since it means the poster was thoughtful enough to reduce it to something easy to play with. Again, though, I can't change the bug report's text.

Comment: @imallett My comment was based on being familiar with connect and the sort of information they need before they will investigate an issue. What's the point of making it harder for them? Surely the goal is to get the bug fixed.

Comment: The `template<>` construct looks mighty suspicious to me. Is it even valid syntax? What's the purpose of a template without parameters?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it's called [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization); it's relatively common.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems to be a MSVC issue. Quickly compiled it with Clang and -std=c++11, no problems there.

Comment: well if it is internal compiler error, chances are, it is not mandated by standard, so obviously it is MSVC problem

Comment: @Creris: You've missed the point. It could be ill-formed in C++ _and_ trigger an ICE in the compiler. The OP is asking whether that's the case (it's not).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit its still MVSC problem tho, ill or non-ill formed program, they shouldnt cause internal errors

Comment: @Creris: Yes, we all know that. That is not what this question is about. The OP is simply asking whether the program is ill-formed. That's it.

Comment: This is a terrible thing. Checking it in some other compiler is not a proof of anything. Only Standard quotes can really back up that it is correct. Also the fact that MSVC ICEs means there's clearly *some* MSVC issue here, but that does not make the code correct or incorrect.

Comment: An ICE is always a compiler bug. If the C++ is ill-formed, it should trigger a compilation error or warning, never an ICE. File the bug on connect. From the command-ilne, be sure to run ``cl -Bv`` to capture the exact version number